# Issue overriding onDrawerOpened() - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, overriding, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm working on a Kotlin coded app using the Navigation Drawer Layout with a list of items. When I open the drawer using the icon at the top left I want it to notifyDataSetChanged so that the list is updated from outside the MainActivity. This includes pressing the back button, swiping open the drawer, or clicking the stacked lines icon at the top left

Here's a simplified version of my code, but it's essentially a Navagation Drawer Activity with a recyclerView for the context of my question:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var navView: NavigationView
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    navView = nav_view
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    }
```

I've spent several hours trying anything I can, but primarily I can't get this to work:

```
override fun onDrawerOpen(view:View){
    ... myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
super.onDrawerOpen(view)
}
```

it gives me the hint "overrides nothing" or "unused", and if I try to add it to any of my code in onCreate it states "Modifier 'override' not applicable to local function.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to notify a data change when the drawer is opened?

Answer (score 1):

The Question is old, but to whom has the same problem:

Just Create new class that implements `DrawerListener` and write your logic inside appropriate method:

```
private inner class MyDrawerListener(): DrawerListener {
    override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {

    }

    override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
        
    }

    override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {

    }

    override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {

    }
}
```

Now add listener as:

```
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(MyDrawerListener())
```